# About Yahoo weather condition description

Tags: yahoo-api, yahoo-weather-api

I use yahoo weather api to build an app for notification in iPhone.

I record the api data everyday and I found an interesting thing.

Some weather conditions' description are different with the api list.

Such as today's weather description is : Thunderstorms Late

But in http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/ you couldn't find "Thunderstorms Late".

Because I should translate the weather description to Chinese so I need all conditions' description.

Besides,current condition's description are also can't be found in the api list.

I doubt that is there another api list of Yahoo weather?

Answer (score 1):

There is no other API call to get just the list of conditions. My suggestion would be to translate the conditions as listed on the documentation page (codes 0-47). In the (hopefully rare) case of getting a condition not on the list, you can catch those programmatically and add translations over time.

Comment: Yes.Finallly,I choose the way like you say.Thank you.